# How to check whether the input text field contains only white spaces?

Tags: javascript

What is the easiest way to check in Javascript whether the input text field is empty (contains nothing or white spaces only)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for something like **[trim function](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-trim.html)**, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks !
Actually jQuery has a built-in trim() function !

Comment: you didn't say that you were working with jQuery - you get the best answers if you provide more information... the jquery validate plug provides a :blank selector.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/blank

Comment: +1 You are right. I should have mentioned that. Thanks for the :blank !

Comment: the link is broken now, and with current strategy, the answer is more like a `link only` answer

Answer (score 11):

```
var str = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
if (str.match(/^\s*$/)) {
    // nothing, or nothing but whitespace
} else {
    // something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include this function somewhere (in order to provide a trim function)

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
   return this.replace(/^\s*(\S*(\s+\S+)*)\s*$/, "$1");
};
```

see here http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html

then...

```
if (document.forms['id_of_form'].elements['id_of_input'].value.trim()=='') {
    //do xyz
}
```