# How to detect string which contains only spaces?

Tags: javascript

A string length which contains one space is always equal to 1:

```
alert('My str length: ' + str.length);
```

The space is a character, so:

```
str = "   ";
alert('My str length:' + str.length); // My str length: 3
```

How can I make a distinction between an empty string and a string which contains only spaces? How can I detect a string which contain only spaces?

Comment: Trim it and check that the length is zero. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Remove all white space and see whether the string length is `0`? Or use a regular expression to match only whitespace strings...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check whether the input text field contains only white spaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662245/how-to-check-whether-the-input-text-field-contains-only-white-spaces)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a Regular Expression to remove all the whitespace in the string. If the length of the resulting string is `0`, then you can be sure the original only contained whitespace. Here's a working example:

```js
const isWhitespaceString = str => !str.replace(/\s/g, '').length

console.log('isWhitespaceString str1:', isWhitespaceString('  w ')); // false
console.log('isWhitespaceString str2:', isWhitespaceString('    ')); // true
console.log('isWhitespaceString str3:', isWhitespaceString('')); // true
```

Comment: Well, string only contained whitespace.

Comment: You might want to check the length as well, so empty strings are not getting through: `if(str.length>0 && str.replace(/\s/g, '').length==0) { // string has only spaces }`

Answer (score 75):

The fastest solution would be using the regex prototype function [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and looking for any character that is not a space, tab, or line break `\S`:

```js
var str1 = '  w ' // false
var str2 = '    ' // true
var str3 = '' // true

const isWhitespaceString = str => !/\S/.test(str)

console.log('isWhitespaceString str1', isWhitespaceString(str1))
console.log('isWhitespaceString str2', isWhitespaceString(str2))
console.log('isWhitespaceString str3', isWhitespaceString(str3))
```

In case you have a super long string, it can make a significant difference as it will stop processing as soon as it finds a non-space character.

Comment: `/\S/.test("      w ")` is true

Comment: @leavesster Yes, because it found something other than a space. That's the point. I agree that my answer can be misleading though since the condition is true when the string is *not* empty. I'll change it for `!/\S/.test(str)`.

Answer (score 70):

Similar to Rory's answer, with ECMA 5 you can now just call `str.trim().length` instead of using a regular expression. If the resulting value is 0 you know you have a string that contains only spaces.

```
if (!str.trim().length) {
  console.log('str is empty!');
}
```

You can read more about trim [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp).

Edit: After looking at this a few years later I noticed this could be simplified further. Since the result of trim will either be truthy or falsy you can also do the following:

```
if (!str.trim()) {
     console.log('str is empty!');
}
```

Answer (score 44):

```
if(!str.trim()){
  console.log('string is empty or only contains spaces');
}
```

[`String#trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) removes the whitespace at the start and end of the string. If the string contained only whitespace, it would be empty after trimming, and the empty string is falsey in JavaScript.

If the string might be `null` or `undefined`, we need to first check if the string itself is falsey before trimming.

```
if(!str || !str.trim()){
   //str is null, undefined, or contains only spaces
}
```

This can be simplified using the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```
if(!str?.trim()){
   //str is null, undefined, or contains only spaces
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can Trim your String value by creating a trim function for your Strings.

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
}
```

now it will be available for your every String and you can use it as

```
str.trim().length// Result will be 0
```

You can also use this method to remove the white spaces at the start and end of the String i.e

```
"  hello  ".trim(); // Result will be "hello"
```

Comment: Extending built-in objects' prototypes is a bad idea.

Comment: @exizt: what if it will only be used by his own code?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by simply using trim.

```js
var str = "   ";
if (str.trim().length == 0)
{
   console.log("Your string contains only white spaces.")
   console.log(`Your string is >>${str}<<`);
}
```

Comment: added log statement to prove string is not modified in place

Answer (score 2):

If we want to check if string contains only white spaces, then this might be helpful.

```
const str = '   ';
console.log(/^\s+$/.test(str));
```

This will log true.

Comment: This will return true for any string containing spaces, not only those containing only spaces.

Comment: Current version fixes above comment

Answer (score 1):

Trim your String value by creating a trim function

```
var text = "  ";
if($.trim(text.length == 0){
  console.log("Text is empty");
}
else
{
  console.log("Text is not empty");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typecasting to `Number` can detect whitespace-only strings (if strings containing only zeros can be excluded):

```
if (+'   ' === 0) console.log('is whitespace');
```

to make this approach also work for empty- and zerostrings like '0' a truthy numerical prefix could be used:

```
if (Number('1 0') === 1) console.log('is not whitespace');
if (Number('1 ' + ' \n ') === 1) console.log('is whitespace');
```

but concatenated casting is expensive - leading to this obscure expression:

```
String(x || '').indexOf('0') < +x
```

however, performance- and readability wise - trimed-length still wins over regex or casting-magic.

```js
const tests = ['',' ', '\t\n\r','0',' 0 ','x',' 404 '];

tests.filter(x => String(x || '').trim().length === 0); // fastest
tests.filter(x => /^\s*$/.test(x)); // 33% slower
tests.filter(x => +x === 0 && String(x).indexOf('0') === -1); // 40 % slower
tests.filter(x => String(x || '').indexOf('0') < +x); // 50% slower
tests.filter(x => Number('1 ' + x) === 1); // 66% slower
```

Answer (score -1):

**This works in Dart not Javascript. However, when I searched up how to do this with Dart this question came up, so I figured others may need the Dart answer.**

```
String foo = '        ';
if (foo.replaceAll(' ', '').length == 0) {
print('ALL WHITE SPACE');
}
else {
print('NOT ALL WHITE SPACE');
}
```

To further clarify, the String `'    d   '` will print 'NOT ALL WHITE SPACE' and the String `'       '` will print 'ALL WHITE SPACE'.

Comment: This answer should be added to a question with tags related to `Dart`