# difference between {key:""} and {key:" "}, json file?

Tags: javascript, json, express, middleware, express-validator

I am trying to implement validation on my express Router, The problem is When i pass {title:""} the express-validator didn't throw error , but when i pass {title:" "} it works .

```
exports.postValidatorCheck = [
  check("title", "The title must not we empty").isEmpty(),
  check("title", "The Length of the Title should be in greater then 10").isLength({
    min: 10,
    max: 1500
  }),
  function(req, res, next) {
    let errors = validationResult(req);
    console.log(errors);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      const firstError = errors.errors.map(err => err.msg)[0];
      return res.status(400).json({ error: firstError });
    }
    next();
  }
];
```

jSON file:

```
{
"title":"",
"body":"This is a new Post"
}
```

No error

JSON file

```
{
"title":" ",
"body":"This is new post"
}
```

Error as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation should use the negative:

```
check("title", "The title must not we empty").not().isEmpty()
```

This will make sure the `title` is not empty, which is what I think you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `""` is an empty string. `" "` is not; it contains a space character. If you would like to count any whitespace as empty, you should use a [regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261986/how-to-detect-string-which-contains-only-spaces).

As for your actual issue, you're testing for `isEmpty()` when you should be testing for `not().isEmpty()`.

Comment: so, when I pass  {title:""} express-validator  should throw an error, but it didn't ,it validate the title and moves on.