# Skip or remove newline within pre and code tags in string

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, newline, line-breaks

So currently I'm going for the effect of trying to display formatted code or in this case a graphql operation in my react app. Triggered by state, I want to display or remove certain variables.

```
const testing = `query {
  getBooks {
    ${value.bookId?"id" : ""}
    ${value.bookEntry?"entry" : ""}
    ${value.bookTitle?"title" : ""}
  }
}`

...

<div className="output">
  <pre>
    <code>{testing}</code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

I'm stuck rendering something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JUG6.png)!

There's probably a better way to go around this, but it's worth asking!

Comment: create a function that will form new testing depending on your checkboxes

Comment: and then you can update text field by turning `testing` into a state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a filter to remove whitespaces before rendering.

Check my solution below:

```js
// Solution:
function clearQueryString(queryString){
  const result = []
  const splitted = queryString.split('\n')
  console.log({splitted})

  for (let index = 0; index < splitted.length; index++) {
    const element = splitted[index];

    // regex credit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261986/how-to-detect-string-which-contains-only-spaces/50971250
    if (!element.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {
      console.log(`#${index} string only contains whitespace!`);
    } else {
      result.push(element)
    }
  }

  return result.join('\n')
}

// Usage:
const value = {}
const testing = `query {
  getBooks {
    ${value.bookId?"id" : ""}
    ${value.bookEntry?"entry" : ""}
    ${value.bookTitle?"title" : ""}
    author
    otherfield 
  }
}`

document.getElementById('codeOutput').innerHTML = clearQueryString(testing);
```

```html
<div className="output">
  <pre>
    <code id="codeOutput"></code>
  </pre>
</div>
```